# how do i pass a double value to a C++ parameter using DLLImport?

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I have a C++ method and it takes a parameter of type double e.g.

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl GetResult (double resultLine);
}
```

On the C# side, I can call the method but it always converts the resultLine value to 0.  I am calling the C++ DLL method using DLLImport's extern feature:

```
internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
{
const string _dllLocation = "CoreDLL.dll";
[DllImport(_dllLocation)]
public static extern void GetResult(double resultLine);
}
```

I can call the other methods that take the string value and everything works but for some reason, it doesn't work when I pass the double value.

Is that the correct way to pass the double value? or do I need to use ref/out etc?

Comment: Please show the exact C++ function definition from the .H file, and the entire DLLImport statement from your C# program.

Comment: Done above, let me know if it's unclear.

Comment: It's clear. See the answer below about calling convention. If that doesn't solve the problem, then there's a problem somewhere else in your code. You'll want to single-step to be sure that the value you're passing really is something other than zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is related, but the fundamental mistake I see here is that you got the calling convention wrong. If you don't specify anything, the `DllImport` attribute will use the `Winapi` calling convention, which is actually `__stdcall`, while you need `__cdecl`.

To fix this problem set the [`CallingConvention`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention.aspx) field to [`CallingConvention.Cdecl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx):

```
internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
{
const string _dllLocation = "CoreDLL.dll";
[DllImport(_dllLocation), CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl]
public static extern void GetResult(double resultLine);
}
```

or set the calling convention to `__stdcall` on the C++ side (if you don't need vararg `__stdcall` is also a bit more efficient than `__cdecl`).

Comment: @Preet: thank you, but it's just the OP code with the correction applied. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a mismatch of calling conventions, cdecl on one side and stdcall on the other. Make them match and you should be back in business.